# Converting SuiteSparse.SPQR.QRSparseQ to SparseMatrixCSC?

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have this problem that converting the native sparse format for the QR decomposition of a sparse Matrix takes forever. However, I need it in the CSC format to use it for further computations.

```
using LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays
N = 1000
A = sprand(N,N,1e-4)
@time F = qr(A)
@time F.Q
@time Q_sparse = sparse(F.Q)

0.000420 seconds (1.15 k allocations: 241.017 KiB)
0.000008 seconds (6 allocations: 208 bytes)
6.067351 seconds (2.00 M allocations: 15.140 GiB, 36.25% gc time)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem. For other people trying to do it:

```
factors = F.Q.factors
τ       = F.Q.τ
Nτ = size(factors)[2]
Isp = sparse(I(N));
@time Q_constr = prod(Isp - factors[:,i]*τ[i]*factors[:,i]' for i in 1:Nτ)
Q_constr ≈ Q_sparse

0.084461 seconds (62.64 k allocations: 3.321 MiB, 18.28% gc time)
true
```

You see that the method sparse(F.Q) is somehow using the wrong representation. If you construct Q as I did above, it will be considerably faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer necessary, I tried this out with Julia 1.9.2 and the built in `sparse` function is much faster. I increased the size of the problem to emphasize the difference.

```julia
using LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays

versioninfo()
println()

N = 3000
A = sprand(N,N,1e-3)

println("Time for the QR decomposition:")
@time F = qr(A)

println("Time for sparse(F.Q):")
@time Q_sparse = sparse(F.Q);

factors = F.Q.factors
τ       = F.Q.τ
Nτ = size(factors)[2]
Isp = sparse(I(N))

println("Time for product of factors:")
@time Q_constr = prod(Isp - factors[:,i]*τ[i]*factors[:,i]' for i in 1:Nτ)

@show Q_constr ≈ Q_sparse;
```

```
Julia Version 1.9.2
Commit e4ee485e909 (2023-07-05 09:39 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: 24 × 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700KF
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-14.0.6 (ORCJIT, goldmont)
  Threads: 1 on 24 virtual cores
Environment:
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 

Time for the QR decomposition:
  0.038390 seconds (172 allocations: 27.693 MiB)
Time for sparse(F.Q):
  0.482476 seconds (2.17 M allocations: 52.746 MiB, 0.22% gc time)
Time for product of factors:
 19.402788 seconds (146.44 k allocations: 56.723 GiB, 1.22% gc time, 0.10% compilation time)
Q_constr ≈ Q_sparse = true
```